# Use null or Empty singleton in c# class?

Tags: c#, oop, null

I often stumble on classes with an Empty-property to denote a value that is unknown or missing somehow. Why not use null instead? Are there any good practical reason for having an Empty singleton of a class? Or a struct for that matter given that we can use a nullable property in that case.

Clarification: I mean not whether I should use existing Empty-like-properties or null but if/when I should add Empty-properties for new classes I implement myself.

Update:

I think I just confused aspects of coding with domain modeling. It's obviously up to every domain to regard certain Empty-like values as unacceptable or not, such as empty string, empty array, 0, Guid.Empty etc.

If an underlying value type has states that is not valid for the concept that my class represents, then I could add Empty, Undefined or similar with the invalid underlying value to represent this state. But other than this case I cannot think of reasons to add an Empty-property instead of just using null.

Answer (score 0):

> You use a nullable type when you need to represent the undefined value of an underlying type. A `Boolean` variable can have only two values: true and false. There is no "undefined" value. In many programming applications, most notably database interactions, a variable value can be undefined or missing. For example, a field in a database may contain the values true or false, or it may contain no value at all. You use a `Nullable<bool>` type in that case.

The nullable types can be most useful when your application is communicating with third-party Database/Service where you have very limited or absolutely no control.

Let’s assume, one of your application which deals with different sources. You have to assign source values to one of your class which has `Reference Types (string, class, list etc.)` as well as `Value Types (int, double, bool etc)` properties.

You have no control over what values are received in your application. While `Reference Types` will handle any null value gracefully, the `Value Types` will throw runtime exception. This is where the Nullable type will save the day for you. Once the values are assigned to your class properties, you are free to handle them the way you want.

You can get more information on this topic here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to why some programmers write classes with an `Empty` (or `Unknown` or `Undefined`) instance, rather than using `null`, is that it is a programming technique.

Benefit: it provides an instance on which members may be accessed. Much of your code no longer needs to do null checks, as there are never null values passed around; instead this instance is passed around.

Technically speaking: `Empty` **should not** mean `Unknown/Undefined`. For example, `String.Empty` is a useful value when you **don't care** whether a variable has been explicitly set somewhere. Use it if you want code to work, regardless.

If you **care** to detect "never initialized", then you either leave it `null`, or create an `Unknown` (or `Undefined`) instance. This would be identical in implementation to `Empty`, it just is used differently. By convention.

Names matter.

---

I personally don't use this technique. I find it less confusing to perform null checks whereever a value could be null, than to check for this special instance (when I need to know whether it is Unknown or not).

Or to say it another way: I don't like the way this technique tends to "pass the problem on" to other code. To me its more important to detect mistakes as early as possible, than to make programming slightly more convenient. When a programmer writes code, they should "know" (define / decide / declare) whether "null" is permitted at a given point or not. If a "null" is mistakenly passed where it isn't allowed, I *want* an exception immediately.

Some newer languages enforce such knowledge, and always distinguish between "nullable" and "not nullable" variables, even for class instances. This is my preference: "declare" up front. Ideally, if a "null" is permitted, programmer is **required** to say how null is handled. F# does this, IIRC. Or perhaps it is just their "patterns" (a generalization of "switch/case") that require "complete specification".

---

If a class programmer uses this technique, they must **ensure** that an exception is thrown on any attempt to **alter** this special Empty instance.

In most languages, it is quite a chore to **ensure** this: any writable property must contain logic to check whether it is the Empty instance that is being modified. If so, throw an exception.

(String class doesn't have this concern, beccause all instances are *immutable*: any operation that creates an altered string, returns that as a new string instance, leaving the original unchanged.)

Ideally, a language has a "true" "read-only" capability, that can guarantee that an object is "immutable". (Contrast with C# and other C-style languages, which allow a "read-only" variable's properties to still be writable. That is useful, when you want it; what is missing is a way to state that an instance is entirely immutable, yet have other instances that can mutate.)

Answer (score -1):

1. e. g. `string.Empty` makes operations possible, that would fail with `null`, throwing a `NullReferenceException`.
2. if you were using `""` everywhere in your code instead of `string.Empty`, you'd create a new instance of `string` for each usage and thus waste memory.

NB: At least for `string` the `Empty` property is not a `Singleton` but just a static property.

Comment: Thanks, but I should have written "except string" in my question. I personally think String.Empty is a little problematic since I don't really see empty string and null as different. Both are missing values in my eyes. Empty string should probably never be a valid value for a required property.

Comment: don't agree: `string.Empty` has its purpose. Consider composing a string of conditional fragments. Starting with `null` would be p.i.t.a. The same is true for e. g. empty enumerables and the like.

Comment: reagarding the "required property": "required" is determined by the app/domain/... A string composed purely of whitespace (or a list of ints containing only 0s) might be a bad value as well.

Comment: _"you'd create a new instance of string for each usage"_  is false. Look up "string interning".

Comment: Minor nit: *"the Empty property is not a Singleton but just a static property."*  I find this statement odd. The *only* way to implement such an entity in C# is via a static property (or static field). Whether it is correct to refer to that as a Singleton or not is irrelevant...

Comment: `String.Empty` emphatically **does not** mean "Unknown/Undefined". Quite the opposite, it is a value that you use when you don't care whether a string has been given an explicit value. If you need to detect a string variable that has not been initialized, then you leave it `null`.